# Dynamically selecting ng-templates

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-template

I have some Angular templates that I want to be able to dynamically select and show in a particular area of a component template.  Below is some simplified example code of what I am trying to do.

I seems that using `@ViewChild` to "save" a template reference to a class property in this way either does not work, or I am misunderstanding something here.

#### In `example.component.ts`

```
import { Component, TemplateRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

interface INamedTmplExample {
  name: string;
  template: TemplateRef<object>;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
})
export class BulkActionsComponent {
  @ViewChild('templateOne') private tmpl1: TemplateRef<object>;
  @ViewChild('templateTwo') private tmpl2: TemplateRef<object>;

  public tmpls: INamedTmplExample [] = [
    { name: 'One', template: this.tmpl1},
    { name: 'Two', template: this.tmpl2},
  ];
  public selectedTmpl: INamedTmplExample | undefined;

  public selectTemplate(tmpl: INamedTmplExample ): void {
    this.selectedTmpl= tmpl;
  }
}
```

#### And then in `example.component.html`:

```
<h1>Choose One</h1>
<button type="button"
        *ngFor="let t of tmpls"
        (click)="selectTemplate(t)">
  {{t.name}}
</button>

<ng-container *ngIf="selectedTmpl">
  <h2>You have selected {{selectedTmpl?.name}}</h2>
 <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="selectedTmpl?.template"></ng-container>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #templateOne>
  <h3>One</h3>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #templateTwo>
  <h3>Two!</h3>
</ng-template>
```

I also tried debugging like this:

```
<pre class="border bg-light p-2">{{tmpls| json}}</pre>
<pre class="border bg-light p-2">{{selectedTmpl| json}}</pre>
```

But that just shows the `INamedTmplExample` object, with the `template` property omitted!

Please advise, I am not sure how I can do what I want to do here.

Comment: `public tmpls: INamedTmplExample [] = ...` might be running before the `ViewChild` elements are available. Maybe you can try running it in `ngAfterViewInit`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but keep in mind that this is example code and there will be many many more templates than this.  I'd rather not have to add a new if statement every time I add a new template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try gathering your `ViewChild` elements in the `ngAfterViewInit` hook:

```
public tmpls: INamedTmplExample [];

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.tmpls = [
        { name: 'One', template: this.tmpl1},
        { name: 'Two', template: this.tmpl2},
    ];
}
```

Comment: I ended up having to use `ngOnInit` instead.  Using `ngAfterViewInit` gave me unrelated errors “Cannot read property 'name' of undefined”, even when I changed the property `name` to have a different name it still gave me that error.  idk what that's about, but anyway doing this fixed it and makes the template stuff work also.